# Intellij cannot recognize classes modified by annotation processor in target/classes

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, annotation-processing

I'm using java annotation processor tool to modify java AST, and the modified classes is generated to `target/classes`. (Not generate java sources to `target/generated-sources/annotations`)

For example, i add a getter method just like lomboks did, but IDEA seems cannot recognize the getter method. I have been searching for a long time, but cannot find a solution. Can anyone help me, thanks!

Note: The class decompiled by IDEA has getter method, and the test code works well although IDEA shows no method error.

```
TestLombok l = new TestLombok();
l.name = "aaa";
System.out.println(l.getName()); // IDEA show no method error
```

[Test code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnIaO.png)

Comment: Please use your code  in details,it needs more clarification.

Comment: Please use your code  in details,it needs more clarification.